# Export a single application display to VNC

Tags: vnc

I'm looking for a script/solution to export a single linux application display to VNC.

For example :

A client browses a web page; it requires authentification (basic username password).

After being authentified, he gets a page with different buttons; each button is related to an application.

For example; clicking on the 'firefox' button, will launch a VNC connection and will only display the firefox application window (no desktop, no right click), only the application.

If the user 'logs out' (provided by a button) or simply drops the connection; the application must remain running and next time he connects back, the application (or VNC) opens in the same state as he leaved the app.

If someone can help, or give me some clues on how to get started it would be nice. If someone is interested in this project, we can have some funds too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xzibit is a Mutter (window manager) plugin that allow individual window sharing over VNC. Might be worth a look: http://telepathy.freedesktop.org/wiki/Xzibit