# Does an online fiddle for qt exist

Tags: qt

I am aware of this post [Is there a fiddle type thing for c++ and other languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338820/is-there-a-fiddle-type-thing-for-c-and-other-languages) which discusses the existence of jsfiddle-type pages for c++ and other languages.

Looking at those pages made me wonder (and a google search didn't turn up anything useful) whether something like this exists for qt? (unless I missed something very obvious and it is in fact available on those pages!??) Obviously the GUI layer adds a large complication but given things like the one shown here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ttlaK_OT6pQ where a qt application is 'put ont he web' using an html5 canvas made me at least want to post the question.

Comment: Such a thing doesn't exist IIRC, but it should be doable. There are HTML5 VNC clients, and it's trivial to expose a Qt application over VNC.

Comment: @KubaOber that would be a completely different question, but since I never worked with VNC, do you have any pointers on how one would do that (exposing qt via VNC)? There is this question, but it seems for a specific wm http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509900/export-a-single-application-display-to-vnc/4126550#4126550

Comment: There used to be a [vnc platform plugin in Qt 4](https://www.qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/68da9153731a931a395d30255823b180e1730275:src/plugins/platforms/vnc), but nobody wished to bring it up to date for Qt 5. It's still a doable task, of course.

Comment: The demo you refer to doesn't put anything on the web, it merely emulates a platform for Qt and runs all of the code in the browser. It's an awful waste of resources and the common consumers of webapps (people with mobile devices) would hate you for draining their battery in an hour :/

Comment: A more recent development that does the same thing would be the [emscripten-qt project](http://vps2.etotheipiplusone.com:30176/redmine/projects/emscripten-qt/wiki). It "mostly works", but again, your browser is essentially running a virtual machine in javascript and emulates a simple framebuffer-based system. The compilation proceeds as follows: C++ -> LLVM IR -> javascript, using typed arrays for virtual memory. It's a vast waste of CPU cycles. There are much better ways of doing it, just that nobody bothered yet :)

Comment: ok, great, I'll take a look at those. Arguably many approaches will just be burning CPU cycles, but the use case for me would be more one of having a very specialized application run in a browser so personally I am not worried about draining people's mobile device batteries.